# load the html data from a text file into postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql

We have a text file it contains rich text data it has to be loaded into the PostgreSQL table.

We tried loading through "COPY" command but it throwing an error **(SQL state: 22P04)**

```
copy tmp_x(description) from 'C:/Jaspersoft/jasperreports-server-6.2.0/postgresql/data/descriptions/BusinessAccountServices.txt' encoding 'windows-1251';
```

Comment: perhaps you're forgetting to declare the delimiters...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **complete** error message (do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Can you include some of the source file. If you are copying from a downloaded web page it may need something like Pythons Beautiful soup ?

Comment: it is text file with html data. we can't specify any delimiter.

Comment: my requirement,I have the list of files in a folder.The file name is the customer name which is there in the database. We need compare the file name with data base customer name if both matches then i need to update the content of the file into a column. File format is text and the content of the file is  <div style="width:65%; display:table-cell; position:relative; left:20px">
<span style="color:#0000FF; font-weight:bold">SEPA Credit Transfer (SEPA)</span>
<ul>
 <li>Efficient</li>
 <li>Secure</li>
 <li>Easy</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>